# Angular Parent scope value in child controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, scope

I have to states: Dashboard and Dashboard.Accounts.
Each one has its own controller and DashboardCtrl is parent controller for AccountsCtrl.
The question is how to access in child controller the scope var in parent controller?
I have tryed to write in AccountCtrl

```
console.log($scope.var);
```

But it tells me *undefined*.

Parent Controller:

```
.controller("DashboardCtrl", ["$scope", "$location", "userSvc",function ($scope, $location, authenticationSvc, userSvc) {
    $scope.getAccounts = function() {
        userSvc.getAccounts($scope.userInfo.accessToken, $scope.userInfo.companyId).
            then(function (result) {
                $scope.accounts = result;
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };
    $scope.getAccounts();
}])
```

getAccounts function in userSvc:

```
function getAccounts(accessToken, companyId) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            url: "/api/accounts"
            method: "GET",
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            }).
            then(function (result) {
                if(result.data.error === 0) {
                    accounts = result.data.data;
                    deferred.resolve(result.data.data);
                }
                else {
                    deferred.reject(error);
                }
            }, function (error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

And finally AccountCtrl:

```
.controller("AccountCtrl", ["$scope", "$location", "$window", "$state", "$stateParams", "userSvc", function($scope, $location, $window, $state, $stateParams, userSvc) {
  console.log($scope.accounts);
};
```

Comment: show the rest of the code.

Comment: $scope.$parent is a reference to parent scope.

Comment: I tried even this way $scope.$parent.accounts, no way =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wouldn't work, because at the time that `AccountCtrl` function runs, `$scope.accounts` is still undefined - it will become defined once your promise resolves asynchronously.

If you want to react to this event in `$scope.accounts`, then you should use [`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope/#$watch):

```
$scope.$watch("accounts", function(){
  console.log($scope.accounts);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! And little addition, seems like if I use $scope.accounts in template as {{accounts}} at the same time - it wouldn't work.